# How to close bootstrap dropdown when input checked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use  [dropdowns-enhancement.js](https://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/) when I select on of the inputs(type=checkobox), I want to close the bootstrap dropdown

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Choose</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form-field" id="one" value="">
        <label for="one">One</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form-field" id="two" value="">
        <label for="two">Two</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your spend time

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it.
By Giving an id to your dropdown and then use that id to toggle the dropdown class of bootstrap.

Just Give your button a id like

`<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownBtn">Choose</button>`

now on the click of your checkbox just toggle the dropdown class

`$("input[name='form-field']").click(function() {
   $("#dropdownBtn").dropdown("toggle");
});`

i think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
It may help you:
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>  <span class="caret"></span>Choose
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1">
              <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;One</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1">
              <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Two</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
$(".btn-group").find(".dropdown-menu").find('li').click(function(){
      $(this).parent(".btn-group").removeClass("open");
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Ashish Thanks, i will take care for this in future.